# GCP Cloudrun - cant reliably get my print statements in the log explorer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

Seems like a question posed without much research, but please bear with me and read thru the whole question.

I have a service that is running on Cloudrun. Most of the code is in Python. I have print statements in different places in my code (not using logging or anything fancy - just good old print(f"whatever") type of print statements). I tried all the various solutions/recommendations on stackoverflow and other places without any luck. I just cant reliably get the print statements to show in my GCP log explorer. It's not that none of them show. I just cant get all of them to show. I tried setting the log severity to level to select all....tried all kinds of things without any luck. Would greatly appreciate some help.

Comment: Without an example with code and results, we can only guess. The correct implementation is to add logging to your application. https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/samples/cloudrun-manual-logging